# SSH & SCP between two EC2 instances times out

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, scp

I would like to transfer/tunnel between two Amazon EC2 instances via `ssh` and `scp` (from A to B, as shown below).

Both instances are running Ubuntu 18.04.

- Instance A: ec2-34-200-134-210.compute-1.amazonaws.com
- Instance B: ec2-34-199-133-209.compute-1.amazonaws.com

Run on Instance A:

- `$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096`
- Result put at `/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa` and `/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`
- `$ chmod 400 /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`
- Copy `/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` contents

Run on Instance B:

- `$ sudo vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config`
- Add/uncomment lines:

  - `RSAAuthentication yes`
  - `PubkeyAuthentication yes`
- Append copied contents of `/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` from Instance A to `/home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Now, testing from A to B:

```
ubuntu@ip-XX-XX-XX-XX:~$ ssh -T ubuntu@ec2-34-199-133-209.compute-1.amazonaws.com
ssh: connect to host ec2-34-199-133-209.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection timed out

ubuntu@ip-XX-XX-XX-XX:~$ touch testfile.txt && \
>    scp testfile.txt ubuntu@ec2-34-199-133-209.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/home/ubuntu/
ssh: connect to host ec2-34-199-133-209.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection timed out
```

What am I missing here?  Do I need to change additional file permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with Inbound Rules on the security group that applied to the cluster of instances.

Solution:

1. On the EC2 dashboard at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/, navigate to Security Groups on the left-hand pane.
2. Select the security group that applies to Instance B, the instance to which you want to tunnel to.
3. Add an Inbound Rule on the Inbound tab > Edit.  Type: SSH; Port: 22, IP Address: 10.XX.XX.XX/32 where 10.XX.XX.XX is the private IPv4 of Instance A.
4. Save the rule and log out/log in of Instance A, then re-test as above.

Comment: To clarify... A security group applies to an instance. If multiple instances have the same security group, then that security group is applied individually to each instance. Instances within the same security group cannot communicate with each other unless the security group has a rule that allows the inbound connection. That best way to configure this is to allow the inbound connection **with the security group itself as the source** (rather than using an IP address range). That is, the security group can refer to itself.

Comment: Ah, got it @JohnRotenstein.  Thanks for the tip.